# What is the difference between HTML lang attribute and LINK hreflink attribute?

Tags: seo, google-search, local-seo, multilingual, google-local-search

Let say example.com has two different country version apart from main English version

1. Israel(example.il)
2. New Zealand(example.nz)

What SEO practice should I follow.

Method 1 - **HTML lang**

```
example.com
<html lang="en">
example.il
<html lang="he-IL">
example.nz
<html lang="en-NZ">
```

Method 2 - **HTML hreflang link**
inside head tag
example.com

```
<head>
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/" 
      hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.il/" 
      hreflang="he-IL" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.nz/" 
      hreflang="en-NZ" />
</head>
```

similarly use the same for other pages(example.il,example.nz).

Google says from 2011 they started treating link with `hreflang` for mentioning language specific content.
Now Which method should I use to make the site language and country specific when it comes to search engines?

What is the difference between `<html lang>` and `<link hreflang>` ?

Answer (score 4):

> Which method should I use ...
>
> What is the difference between `<html lang>` and `<link hreflang>`.

You can use both.

The `lang` attribute on the `html` tag informs user-agents the language of the current document.

The `hreflang` attribute informs user-agents/bots of the location of alternative localised versions of the current document.

In a way they are complementary.

However, Google most probably ignores the `lang` attribute and auto-detects the document language instead. I believe Google ignores all language identifiers, except for `hreflang`.

`hreflang` on the other hand is recommended by Google to help indexing of multi-lingual websites. So, if you needed to choose one or the other then the `hreflang` would be the one to go for.